# How to uninstall "LiveUSB" package?

Tags: software-center, uninstall, live-usb, deb

I've installed the [LiveUSB](http://live.learnfree.eu/download) programme using the DEB file. What is the best way to remove the installer as I cannot find it in the software centre; is it just a python programme that can be deleted?

Comment: Hello. Try `sudo dpkg -r package_name`.

Comment: Then I'll type it as an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In order to uninstall a `.deb` package you can run, from the command line:

```
 sudo dpkg -r package_name
```